# Google Chrome eating borders (works fine on firefox)

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser

Please consider this snippet: http://fruple.com/kemper/test/categorie.html

### Firefox screenshot:

[image]

### Chrome screenshot

[image]

why are some of the right borders not showing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `display` property for the `li` elements from `inline` to `inline-block`.

Comment: @kemp Actually, I'd say that [RoToRa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095257/google-chrome-eating-borders-works-fine-on-firefox/4095326#4095326) is better, since he actually found the cause of the problem, while I merely found a workaround. Also, **always** use a `doctype` :)

Comment: well RoToRa's answer points to a bug report, not a solution. I updated the snippet to use the actual doctype of the original page, but the bug is still there. Your workaround seems like the proper solution :)

Comment: @kemp Oh, okay, fair enough then *(stops feeling guilty)*

Comment: although that breaks IE6 but that's no news to anyone, is it :)

Comment: Everyone should stop supporting IE6 anyway. Not even MS supports it anymore!

Answer (score 2):

It's possibly related to this bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58105

You should avoid triggering quirks mode in any case and add a DOCTYPE.

Comment: the original page has an HTML5 doctype and same behavior

Comment: Ok, but it seems to be a bug. You should consider reporting it.

Comment: Yes definitely, thanks for the link I didn't find it in my quick search